# How do I output only one SQL result?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I would like to output only 1 SQL result from multiple results.
For example my SQL results from 'iso_id' and 'total' only needs to be shown once, but my 'name' needs to show all the SQL results.
Currently it shows 10 values of 'GBR' where I want this to just 1.
Thanks

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT Country.ISO_id, total, Cyclist.name FROM Cyclist LEFT JOIN Country ON Cyclist.ISO_id = Country.ISO_id WHERE Country.ISO_id LIKE '$first%';
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var valu2='<?php echo $valu2?>'; 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#stub5").text("The value is: "+valu2);
        var obj2 = JSON.parse(valu2);
        for(field in obj2) {
            $("#stub6").append( "<div>" + obj2[field].iso_id +"</div>" ); 
            $("#stub7").append( "<div>" + obj2[field].total +"</div>" );
            $("#stub8").append( "<div>" + obj2[field].name +"</div>" );
        }
    })      
</script>
```

Here is my output:

```
<td id="stub7"></td>
```

Comment: pls can you provide your json response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `iso_id` and `total` are always same values in your result set, you would just have to remember if you appended them before or not:

```
var valu2='<?php echo $valu2?>'; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#stub5").text("The value is: "+valu2);
    var obj2 = JSON.parse(valu2);
    var showISO = true;
    for(field in obj2) {
        if (showISO) {
            $("#stub6").append( "<div>" + obj2[field].iso_id +"</div>" );
            $("#stub7").append( "<div>" + obj2[field].total +"</div>" );
            showISO = false;
        }
        $("#stub8").append( "<div>" + obj2[field].name +"</div>" );
    }
})
```

Hope i got your question right and this will help